# Substitutions with numbering on certain intervals

Tags: awk, sed

I would like to have some simple sed command that when applied to a standard output of the type

```
\partie
{Méthode}
{Méthode} 

\partie
{Méthode} 
{Méthode} 

\partie
{Méthode}
{Méthode}
{Méthode}

\partie
{Méthode}
```

... transforms it into

```
\partie
{Méthode 1}
{Méthode 2} 

\partie
{Méthode 1} 
{Méthode 2} 

\partie
{Méthode 1}
{Méthode 2}
{Méthode 3}

\partie
{Méthode 1}
```

I understand that awk allows to insert numbers after each "Méthode", but how can I put the counter back to 1 after an occurence of "\partie"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F'}' '/\partie/{ c=0 }/Méthode/{ print $1,++c"}"; next }1' file
```

- `-F'}'` - optional/auxiliary field separator
- `/\partie/{ c=0 }` - resetting counter on each `\partie` occurrence

Answer (score 2):

Using **awk** :

```
awk '/\partie/{c=0}/^\{/{sub(/\}/," "++c"&")}1' infile
```

**Explanation**

```
awk '/\partie/{c=0}/^\{/{sub(/\}/," "++c"&")}1' infile
         ^      ^    ^        ^              ^
         |      |    |        |              |
         |      |    |        |         1 at end does default operation print current record/line/row that is print $0
         |      |    |     substitute } with space followed by variable c value and matched regexp
         |      |    |
         |      |  look for line starts with {
         |      |
         |   reset variable c
         |
      search for line with \partie
```

From [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) :

> If the special character ‘&’ appears in replacement, it stands for the
>   precise substring that was matched by regexp. (If the regexp can match
>   more than one string, then this precise substring may vary.)

**Input**

```
$ cat infile
\partie
{Méthode}
{Méthode} 

\partie
{Méthode} 
{Méthode} 

\partie
{Méthode}
{Méthode}
{Méthode}

\partie
{Méthode}
```

**Output**

```
$ awk '/\partie/{c=0}/^\{/{sub(/\}/," "++c"&")}1' infile
\partie
{Méthode 1}
{Méthode 2} 

\partie
{Méthode 1} 
{Méthode 2} 

\partie
{Méthode 1}
{Méthode 2}
{Méthode 3}

\partie
{Méthode 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

with **awk**:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/\partie/{ p=0 }
/Méthode/ && sub(/}/, " " ++p "}"){}1
```

Explanation:

```
/\partie/{ p=0 }       # if the line read ($0) matches `\partie` 
                       # set variable p to 0
```

next, if

```
/Méthode/              # if the line read matches `Méthode`
&&                     # AND
sub(/}/, " " ++p "}")  # substitite "}" with 
                       # concat of "space, pre-increment of p and }"
                       # in $0 succeeds
{}                     # do nothing
1                      # print $0
```

Let's try this **commandline**:

```
$ less input.txt | awk '/\partie/{ p=0 } /Méthode/ && sub(/}/, " " ++p "}"){}1'
```

with your input in input.txt:

```
$ cat input.txt
\partie
{Méthode}
{Méthode}

\partie
{Méthode}
{Méthode}

\partie
{Méthode}
{Méthode}
{Méthode}

\partie
{Méthode}
```

or call it as a script:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk input.txt
\partie
{Méthode 1}
{Méthode 2}

\partie
{Méthode 1}
{Méthode 2}

\partie
{Méthode 1}
{Méthode 2}
{Méthode 3}

\partie
{Méthode 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{sub(/}/," "c++"&")} !NF{c=0} 1' file
\partie
{Méthode 1}
{Méthode 2}

\partie
{Méthode 1}
{Méthode 2}

\partie
{Méthode 1}
{Méthode 2}
{Méthode 3}

\partie
{Méthode 1}
```

Comment: Many thanks to all, I couldn't have had a faster and clearer answer. That was my first question, and certainly not the last!